# its returning an error that TABLE expected not TABLEregister, my table name is register

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
       db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME );
}
```

its returning an error that TABLE expected not TABLEregister, my table name is register

Comment: Also, please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME);
```

instead of

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME );
```

Note the space between `Table` and closing quotes.

Comment: You can upvote and accept to show other users the problem is solved.